# Emacs, hl-line background. How set background color with transparent?

Tags: emacs

Windows 7, Emacs 25.1

If I want to change background color of **hl-line** I do:

```
(set-face-background 'hl-line "#333333")
```

OK. But how I can set transparent (e.g. 50%) for **hl-line** background color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you **cannot** do what you ask. An Emacs *frame* can have an `alpha` parameter that specifies that the frame be transparent to a given degree. But the same is not true for an Emacs face.

---

However:

- You can, for example, make the background of face `hl-line` be close to but slightly different from the frame background color.
- If you want to make text shown in a given face "disappear" against the background, you can give the face used for that text a `foreground` color that is the same as the frame's (i.e. `default` face's) `background` color.